# Displaying Currency symbol in Chart.JS 4 within Blazor

Tags: c#, chart.js, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using Chart.Js (version 4.1) in Blazor and have managed to get a simple line graph up and running.

Now I need to add the currency symbol to the y Axis (which displays sales total), at the moment it simple displays a number as 4,222

My current Options and DataSets anonymous types are below, these are sent to Chart.JS via JS Interops.  Below is what I have tried so far which fails to include the symbol in the tool tip and y axis.

```
var config = new
{
    Type = Type.ToString().ToLower(),
    Options = new
    {
        Responsive = true,
        Scales = new
        {
            y = new
            {
                ticks = new
                {
                    color = "white"
                },
                grid = new
                {
                    color = "white",
                    borderColor = "white",
                    drawOnChartArea = false
                },
                scaleLabel = new
                {
                    display = true,
                    labelString = "Sales Total £",
                    fontColor = "white"
                }
            },
            x = new
            {
                ticks = new
                {
                    color = "white"
                },
                grid = new
                {
                    color = "white",
                    borderColor = "white",
                    drawOnChartArea = false
                    }
                }
            },
            Tooltips = new
            {
                Callbacks = new
                {
                    Label = "function(tooltipItem, data) { return '$' + tooltipItem.value; }"
                }
            }
        },
    Data = ChartData
};
```

What do I need to modify above to include the currency symbol in the tooltip and yAxis?

Answer (score 0):

Since v3 the tooltip is located under plugins in options: [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html)

This is how it looks in javaScript:

```
options:{        
    ...
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (context) {
                    if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                        return context.dataset.label + ": " +
                            new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
                                style: 'currency',
                                currency: 'EUR'
                            }).format(context.parsed.y);
                    }
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

For the y-axis you also can use a callback:

```
options:{
    ...
    scales: {
        y: {          
            ticks: {
                callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
                    return new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
                        style: 'currency',
                        currency: 'EUR'
                    }).format(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Attention, note that it is called "tooltip," not "tooltips"!

Comment: This is the javascript setup object, however I was looking for the c# anonymous type equivalent for a blazor project.

Comment: That's true.
But I guess the schematic is the same.
So insted of "Options", "Tooltips" you need "options", "plugins", "tooltip" and than the "Callbacks" like you have it.

Hope you can adapt it to C#